# Can I set SQL Azure Vunerability Assesment at a server level instead of database level?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

So Recently I found a pretty neat feature where SQL Azure can schedule [vunerability assesment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-vulnerability-assessment) scans regularly

To configure this you must go onto each database on your server and configure the storage and who you want to receive the reports.

Lets say I have 100 databases - this is going to take a very long time. Is there a way I can set the Vunerability scan at a server level.

Or failing that a script that can set this scan up (prefereably SQL script if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can configure this at the server level as shown below.

[image]

However, periodic scans can only be configured at the database level. Azure SQL Database team mentioned that they will provide more options to run scans and analyze results at scale. The currently available option is to use ARM APIs via the [Azure SQL Management SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql) library.

Azure SQL Database team mentioned also that PowerShell cmdlets will be released in the near future to enable automation via PowerShell Scripts, and as they make more progress the ability to run at scale will be available via the portal as well.

Comment: that is just informing you what is included in `Advanded Thread Protection` there is an extra step to actually configure it to scan

Comment: Allow me some time to get a definitive answer for you.

Comment: Please read my answer again as I updated it according to the answer received from Azure SQL Database team.

Answer (score 1):

Currently in SQL Vulnerability Assessment, the target storage and periodic scans can be configured only at the database level.
As the feature develops, we will provide more options to run scans and analyze results at scale.

The currently available option is to use ARM APIs via the Azure SQL management SDK: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql

Powershell cmdlets will be released in the near future to enable automation via Powershell scripts.
And as we make more progress, the ability to run at scale will be available via the portal as well.

In the meantime, we’re very glad to get further feedback on the current functionality of VA and additional feature requests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My use case is that I have 100 clients with seperate databases all with the same schema and I am looking to configure this security scan for all databases